# Windows equivalent of move_pages syscall

Tags: c++, c, linux, windows, numa

I'd like to move some physical pages to different NUMA node. It can be done natively on Linux by using `move_pasges` syscall. Does Windows have anything like this? I read [Windows NUMA API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/procthread/numa-support) and did not find anything similar, the only thing you can do is to allocate memory on specific NUMA node.